# Understanding the code in pyTorch

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, torch, pytorch

I am having problems with understanding the following part of the code from ResNet architecture. The full code is available at https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/deep_residual_network/main-gpu.py . I am not very familiar with Python.

```
# Residual Block
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1, downsample=None):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = conv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, stride)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = conv3x3(out_channels, out_channels)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.downsample = downsample

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        if self.downsample:
            residual = self.downsample(x)
        out += residual
        out = self.relu(out)
        return out

# ResNet Module
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block, layers, num_classes=10):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = 16
        self.conv = conv3x3(3, 16)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.layer1 = self.make_layer(block, 16, layers[0])
        self.layer2 = self.make_layer(block, 32, layers[0], 2)
        self.layer3 = self.make_layer(block, 64, layers[1], 2)
        self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(8)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64, num_classes)

    def make_layer(self, block, out_channels, blocks, stride=1):
        downsample = None
        if (stride != 1) or (self.in_channels != out_channels):
            downsample = nn.Sequential(
                conv3x3(self.in_channels, out_channels, stride=stride),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
        layers = []
        layers.append(block(self.in_channels, out_channels, stride, downsample))
        self.in_channels = out_channels
        for i in range(1, blocks):
            layers.append(block(out_channels, out_channels))
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        out = self.bn(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.layer1(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = self.avg_pool(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

resnet = ResNet(ResidualBlock, [3, 3, 3])
```

My main question is why should we pass 'block' every time? In the function

```
def make_layer(self, block, out_channels, blocks, stride=1):
```

instead of passing 'block' why cant we create an instance of 'ResidualBlock' and append it with layers as follows?

```
   block = ResidualBlock(self.in_channels, out_channels, stride, downsample)
   layers.append(block)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResNet` module is designed to be generic, so that it can create networks with arbitrary blocks. So, if you do not pass the `block` which you want to create you'll have to write the name of the block explicitly like below.

```
# Residual Block
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1, downsample=None):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = conv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, stride)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = conv3x3(out_channels, out_channels)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.downsample = downsample

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        if self.downsample:
            residual = self.downsample(x)
        out += residual
        out = self.relu(out)
        return out

# ResNet Module
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layers, num_classes=10):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = 16
        self.conv = conv3x3(3, 16)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.layer1 = self.make_layer(16, layers[0])
        self.layer2 = self.make_layer(32, layers[0], 2)
        self.layer3 = self.make_layer(64, layers[1], 2)
        self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(8)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64, num_classes)

    def make_layer(self, out_channels, blocks, stride=1):
        downsample = None
        if (stride != 1) or (self.in_channels != out_channels):
            downsample = nn.Sequential(
                conv3x3(self.in_channels, out_channels, stride=stride),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
        layers = []
        layers.append(ResidualBlock(self.in_channels, out_channels, stride, downsample))   # Major change here
        self.in_channels = out_channels
        for i in range(1, blocks):
            layers.append(ResidualBlock(out_channels, out_channels))    # Major change here
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        out = self.bn(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.layer1(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = self.avg_pool(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

resnet = ResNet([3, 3, 3])
```

This reduces the capability of your `ResNet` module and binds it with only the `ResidualBlock`. Now, if you create some other type of block (say `ResidualBlock2`), you will need to create another `Resnet2` module specifically for that. So, it's better to create a generic `ResNet` module which takes in the `block` parameter, so that it can be used with different types of blocks.

#### A trivial python example to clarify

Suppose you want to create a function that can apply a mathematical operation on a list and returns its output. So, you might create something like below

```
def exp(inp_list):
    out_list = []
    for num in inp_list:
        out_list.append(math.exp(num))
    return out_list

def floor(inp_list):
    out_list = []
    for num in inp_list:
        out_list.append(math.floor(num))
    return out_list
```

Here, we are doing an exponent and a floor operation on some input list. But, we can do a better job by defining a generic function to do the same as

```
def apply_func(fn, inp_list):
    out_list = []
    for num in inp_list:
        out_list.append(fn(num))
    return out_list
```

and now call this `apply_func` as `apply_func(math.exp, inp_list)` for exponential and as `apply_func(math.floor, inp_list)` for floor function. Also this opens up possibility for any kind of operation.

> Note: It's not a practical example as you can always use `map` or `list comprehension` for achieving the same thing. But, it demonstrates the use clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still I dont understand. In the first case, Is 'block' an alias of the class 'ResidualBlock'? Every time when we call 'block(out_channels, out_channels)' are we not creating a new instance of the 'ResidualBlock'? It would be nice if you give me a simple example instead of explaining RestNet code.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, if I create a new residual block 'RB2' I dont need to change other parts of my code, instead I have to change only the following line 'resnet = ResNet(ResidualBlock, [3, 3, 3])' to 'resnet = ResNet(RB2, [3, 3, 3])'. Am I correct? In that case can I consider the code that you provided is also a correct version of Resnet?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And my code is correct as well and you can use it if you are not planning on creating additional other type of blocks. I'll update my answer with another simple example to clarify.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can look at the example and it should make the concept more clear.